# NSCollectionViewItem double-click action?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

How do I set an action for when a user double clicks an `NSCollectionViewItem`. `NSTableView`, for example, has the `setDoubleAction` method. Is there something similar for `NSCollectionView`?

Thanks

Comment: this [blog]: http://www.springenwerk.com/2009/12/double-click-and-nscollectionview.html will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably want to handle this in your `NSCollectionViewItem`, rather than the `NSCollectionView` itself (to work off your `NSTableView` analogy).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just subclassing the prototype NSView of the NSCollectionView and adding a mouseDown handler.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is ancient, but it comes up as the third result on Google right now, and I've found a different and very straightforward method that I haven't seen documented elsewhere. (I don't just need to manipulate the represented item, but have more complex work to do in my app.)

`NSCollectionView` inherits from `NSView`, so you can simply create a custom subclass and override `mouseDown`. This is not completely without pitfalls - you need to check the click count, and convert the point from the main window to your collection view's coordinate, before using `NSCollectionView`'s `indexPathForItem` method:

```
override func mouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if theEvent.clickCount == 2 {
        let locationInWindow = theEvent.locationInWindow
        let locationInView = convert(locationInWindow, from: NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentView)


        if let doubleClickedItem = indexPathForItem(at: locationInView){
        // handle double click - I've created a DoubleClickDelegate 
        // (my collectionView's delegate, but you could use notifications as well)
...
```

This feels as if I've finally found the method Apple intended to be used - otherwise, there's no reason for `indexPathForItem(at:)` to exist.